# Find the equation whose roots are twice the negative reciprocal of the roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

$f(x) = 3x^6+x^4-2x^3-x+1$

Let the roots of $f(x)$ be $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_6 $

Find the equation whose roots are twice the negative reciprocal of $f(x)$

My question is do I need to find an equation with roots $-\frac{1}{2\alpha_n}$ or $-\frac{2}{\alpha_n}$

I'm thinking I need to find an equation with roots $-\frac{2}{\alpha_n}$

Comment: I think you mean "twice the negative reciprocal of *the roots of* $f(x)$", in which case you're correct.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer oh yup, thank you

Comment: Agree with $-2/\alpha_n$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you